# How to select a fixed time for the due date of an order if there are multiple options?

Tags: javascript, anylogic, job-scheduling

I am modelling a job shop process and use the event block to generate orders for the order arrival process. In action of the event block, the due date of the generated order has to be specified. This value however is not fixed. It should either be 17:45:00 PM, 19:15:00 PM or 20:15:00 PM. However, the possibility that time 17:45:00 is chosen should be twice as likely as the chances for choosing the other two times. How can I define the due date of an order according to these conditions?
[My process looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xSMo.png)

I first tried given the order a fixed due date, like this:

```
Order order = new Order();
// Set due date as fixed time
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,17); 
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,30); 
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0); 
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0); 
order.atrDueDate = cal.getTime();
// proc time for single orders
order.varProcTime = triangular(1,2,3);
order.markParametersAreSet();
enter1.take(order);
```

This works, but I do not know how to choose a due date from 3 different options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the optimal answer and there are more general ways of doing this, but a simple solution would be

```
if(randomTrue(0.5)){//50% chances of choosing this date
   cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,17); 
   cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,45); 
}else if(randomTrue(0.5)){//25% chances of choosing this date
   cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,19); 
   cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,15); 
}else{//25% chances of choosing this date
   cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,20); 
   cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,15); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the if statement logic really helped me. I used 3 different parameters with type date, in which I saved the 3 different times (parDueDate1, parDueDate2 and parDueDate3) instead of using cal.set, so that it is easy to change the due dates in the parameter when necessary. The due date for the order is then set as
order.atrDueDate = parDueDate1 (instead of defining the date in cal.set).